# XSLT - Add new element and value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML and I want to add a new element name with a hard-coded value. How can I achieve it?

XML:

```
<m2:InvokeWebService xmlns:m2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <m2:request>
      <m2:action>ADD</m2:action>      
      <m2:commonDetails>
         <m2:needSupport>Y</m2:needSupport>
      </m2:commonDetails>
      <m2:custDetails>
         <m2:name>Tony,Hawk</m2:name>
         <m2:accountNumber>23232423566</m2:accountNumber>
         <m2:sensitiveCustomer>Y</m2:sensitiveCustomer>         
      </m2:custDetails>      
   </m2:request>
</m2:InvokeWebService>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><m2:InvokeWebService xmlns:m2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <m2:request>
      <m2:action>ADD</m2:action>      
      <m2:commonDetails>
         <m2:needSupport>Y</m2:needSupport>
      </m2:commonDetails>
      <m2:overrideScriptName>NewScript</m2:overrideScriptName>
      <m2:custDetails>
         <m2:name>Tony,Hawk</m2:name>
         <m2:accountNumber>23232423566</m2:accountNumber>
         <m2:sensitiveCustomer>Y</m2:sensitiveCustomer>         
      </m2:custDetails>      
   </m2:request>
</m2:InvokeWebService>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:m2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!--<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>-->
    <!-- Identity template : copy all text nodes, elements and attributes -->   
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  
    <m2:overrideScriptName>CM-PrMtActMg</m2:overrideScriptName>      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

New Element to be added right before the custDetails

```
<m2:overrideScriptName>NewScript</m2:overrideScriptName>
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: Added the XSLT that I tried to implement, sorry I'm new to XSLT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is using a so called *identity transform* pattern.

**Input XML**

```
<m2:InvokeWebService xmlns:m2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <m2:request>
        <m2:action>ADD</m2:action>
        <m2:commonDetails>
            <m2:needSupport>Y</m2:needSupport>
        </m2:commonDetails>
        <m2:custDetails>
            <m2:name>Tony,Hawk</m2:name>
            <m2:accountNumber>23232423566</m2:accountNumber>
            <m2:sensitiveCustomer>Y</m2:sensitiveCustomer>
        </m2:custDetails>
    </m2:request>
</m2:InvokeWebService>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:m2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="m2:custDetails">
        <m2:overrideScriptName>NewScript</m2:overrideScriptName>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<m2:InvokeWebService xmlns:m2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <m2:request>
    <m2:action>ADD</m2:action>
    <m2:commonDetails>
      <m2:needSupport>Y</m2:needSupport>
    </m2:commonDetails>
    <m2:overrideScriptName>NewScript</m2:overrideScriptName>
    <m2:custDetails>
      <m2:name>Tony,Hawk</m2:name>
      <m2:accountNumber>23232423566</m2:accountNumber>
      <m2:sensitiveCustomer>Y</m2:sensitiveCustomer>
    </m2:custDetails>
  </m2:request>
</m2:InvokeWebService>
```

Comment: @TiJ, if the proposed solution is working for  you, please don't forget to mark it as Answer.